# Query the virtual table for a function offset

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, wxwidgets, virtual-functions

Is there a debugging compiler dependent (Visual Studio 2005) method to determine the size of the virtual table for an object or the offset of a specific function? I would like to add some assertions.

The bigger problem (the context): large industrial application, I'm just new with maintenance, I receive "Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. [bla-bla-bla]" Because a virtual function calls goes to the wrong function. The cause? The include files order matters (there's no precompiled header). If "`ws\winundef.h`" (wxWidgets: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/include/wx/msw/winundef.h) is included after "`windows.h`" it works correctly.

**Edit** From the watch window in debugger: wrong function pointer is 0x0a01dec5 [thunk]:MyPanel::`vcall'{696,{flat}}' }' 
, the good function pointer is  0x0a12e041 [thunk]:MyPanel::`vcall'{692,{flat}}' }' 
How can I access this stuff ?

Comment: I don't have a fix, I'm just here to say "I'm sorry you gotta maintain that".

Comment: Use a **forced include** of a `windows.h` wrapper. In Visual Studio you can set that in the project properties.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, some are really using that character!

Comment: @–  Cheers and hth. - Alf Is this "force include" better than the precompiled header?

Comment: My last idea is to access the function through the table (this+692, in the above example), get the name of the function from the pdb file and compare it against expected.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the vtbl doesn't really change between different TUs, so checking it wouldn't help you.

What you need to do is to ensure that you *never* include `<windows.h>` before including wxWidgets headers. If you need to include it at all (and most of the time you shouldn't), include `<wx/msw/wrapwin.h>` instead. Doing this in your PCH (and ensuring that all files in the project do use the PCH) is an almost certain way to solve the problem.

Comment: I already did it (order: `windows.h` before `winundef.h`), but `wrapwin.h` is even better:
`
#if !defined(__WXMSW__)
#define __WXMSW__
#endif 

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <wx/msw/wrapwin.h>
`

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem, but it's not the answer to my question. A bounty may suits you if you get another up vote, but I'm too low on points :(, my first one will be after I get over 1100 points (if ever)